# Item in ListView not stretching correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm using a `ListView` as the ItemTemplate of a `GridView`. The problem is I can't get the textbox inside the listview to fill the available vertical space, instead it only uses as much space as it needs:
[image]

Why is it ignoring the `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` I set?

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    Width="200" 
    SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="1" Content="1"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Should fill everything" />
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your ListView in a GridLayout in this way:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" .... />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" .... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Makes me wonder a bit about the usefulness of the ListView, because if I already have to use a grid I can just go with the grid the whole way. But worked fine.

Comment: Grid is not DataGrid. Grid is a Panel element; its purpose is to control the rendering of the elements it holds (http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx). 
The ListView instead is able to show data elements.